# Why does IFeatureClass.Search fails with -2147215922 (FDO_E_SE_INVALID_NUM_PARTS)?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, classextensions

in a class extension, I'm trying to do search features inside a point feature class(part of a geometric network on an sql server sde database) and I get a -2147215922 (FDO_E_SE_INVALID_NUM_PARTS) error.

The geometry I'm using to create my search filter is actually a Polygon created with the ISegmentCollection.SetCircle function. Basically, I'm trying to find some features inside a circle defined by a point and a radius

```
void CTools::FillArrayWithFeatures(IFeatureClassPtr ipFeatureClass, 
              IPointPtr ipPoint, double fRadius, CAtlArray<IFeature*>* pArrFeature)
{
    //create the geometry
    IGeometryPtr ipGeometry;
    IPolygonPtr ipPolygon(CLSID_Polygon);
    ISegmentCollectionPtr ipSegmentCollection(ipPolygon);
    HRESULT hr = ipSegmentCollection->SetCircle(ipPoint, fRadius);
    ipGeometry = ipSegmentCollection;
    ISpatialReferencePtr ipSpatialRef;
    ipPoint->get_SpatialReference(&ipSpatialRef);
    ipGeometry->putref_SpatialReference(ipSpatialRef);

    //Create the spatial filter
    ISpatialFilterPtr ipSpatialFilter(CLSID_SpatialFilter);
    ipSpatialFilter->putref_Geometry(ipGeometry); 
    BSTR strName;
    ipFeatureClass->get_ShapeFieldName(&strName);
    ipSpatialFilter->put_GeometryField(strName);
    ipSpatialFilter->put_SpatialRel(esriSpatialRelIntersects);

     // Execute the search 
    IFeatureCursorPtr ipFeatureCursor;
    HRESULT hr = ipFeatureClass->Search(ipSpatialFilter, VARIANT_FALSE, &ipFeatureCursor);

    //Fill the array with the results
    if(ipFeatureCursor)
    {
        IFeature* pFoundFeature;
        hr = ipFeatureCursor->NextFeature(&pFoundFeature);
        while(pFoundFeature)
        {
            pArrFeature->Add(pFoundFeature);
            ipFeatureCursor->NextFeature(&pFoundFeature);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The same code works on a personnal geodatabase, but not on an sde sql server

Thanks

Comment: If this is still an issue would you be able to edit your Question to update it with the ArcGIS for Desktop version you are currently using, and any other information that might help elicit an Answer.

Comment: My problem is not version-specific. I happens on different ArcGIS for Desktop versions.

Comment: Is your database able to accept 'curve' geometry types? SDE is very rigid about bad geometries and may be rejecting the curves resulting in 0 parts i.e. an empty feature and then rejecting that too.